# Inner Join not working after two rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Here is my query and it's not showing the 3rd row even though the tables contents match.**

```
SELECT shopcategory_idcategory_name 
FROM shopcategory 
INNER JOIN category ON shopcategory_id=category_id;
```

**Result:**

```
 ================================================================
 | shopcategory_id |   shopcategory_shopid |   category_name    |
 ================================================================
 |        1        |           1          |       Gadgets       |
 |        2        |           2          |     Analog Device   |
 ================================================================
```

**Here is my query that shows it has 3 rows**

```
SELECT * FROM shopcategory;
```

**Result:**

```
===================================================================
| shopcategory_id | shopcategory_shopid | shopcategory_categoryid |
===================================================================
|       1         |          1          |            1            |
|       2         |          2          |            2            |
|       3         |          3          |            3            |
===================================================================
```

**EDIT: Query for my category table**

```
SELECT * category;
```

**Result:**

```
==============================================
|    category_id    |      category_name     |
==============================================
|        1          |        Gadgets         |
|        2          |      Analog Device     |
|        3          |         Beauty         |
|        4          |        Keyboard        |
|        5          |       Instruments      |
|        6          |         Monitor        |
|        7          |         Chairs         |
==============================================
```

Comment: What are the tables name? Try my example and tell me if it works for you? What output would you get?

Comment: Still no 3rd row. It's kinda weird because I inserted a new data and the 4th row is shown.

Comment: Wait, just edited the code! What are the table names??

Comment: And why are you using inner join? I think it should be left join?

Comment: I have done some editting and it resulted with
shopcategory_id, category_name ,category_id

Comment: 4 results, but 3rd row is _NULL_

Comment: Just re-updated! The 3 row is empty, because we didn't query it!

Comment: Anyway, I just trancuated the table and it seem to worked.

Comment: Actually, after trancuating and inserting 3 more data. The 3rd row is still null. But, the 4th one is working.
Weird.

Comment: In `SELECT` you must specify all rows, from all tables, that you want to see in your final results! `LEFT JOIN` is just what I would use here!

Comment: Could it be my localhost MySQL? I have been truncating it and still and always the 3rd is _NULL_

Comment: If it's properly setup it should be no difference, I believe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` here instead and add `aliases` for tables that you are joining on, like this:

```
SELECT 
  tableName1.shopcategory_id,
  tableName1.category_name,
  tableName2.category_id
FROM
  tableName1 as tb1
LEFT JOIN 
  tableName2 AS tb2
ON
  tb1.shopcategory_id = tb2.category_id
GROUP BY 
  tb1.shopcategory_id;
```